# Material-UI not applying color theme to a button as it should be

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to follow [this documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#customized-buttons). I am trying to get Login button to turn green, but it seems to not inherit any theme styling with the given code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have the following code:

```
 import React from "react";
 import {
      createMuiTheme,
      withStyles,
      makeStyles
 } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
 import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
 import green from "@material-ui/core/colors/green";
 import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
 import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
 import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
 import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
 import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
 import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";

 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      root: {
           flexGrow: 1
      },
      menuButton: {
           marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
      },
      title: {
           flexGrow: 1
      }
 }));

 const theme = createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
           primary: green
      }
 });

 export default function ButtonAppBar() {
      const classes = useStyles();

      return (
           <div className={classes.root}>
                <AppBar position="static">
                     <Toolbar>
                          <IconButton
                               edge="start"
                               className={classes.menuButton}
                               color="inherit"
                               aria-label="Menu"
                          >
                               <MenuIcon />
                          </IconButton>
                          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                               Hello
                          </Typography>
                          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                               <Link to="/login">
                                    <Button color="secondary">Login</Button>
                               </Link>
                          </ThemeProvider>
                     </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
           </div>
      );
 }
```

If I were to paste in all the code from the documentation, then I would see the three buttons of each color. But my variation of the code doesn't work.

Comment: do you wrap this component with another themeprovider?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean this button?

```
<Link to="/login">
    <Button color="secondary">Login</Button>
</Link>
```

if so you need to set it to Primary not secondary. You need it wrapped in themeProvider too. If you look at the custom code in that doc you posted you should see this

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.margin}>
          Theme Provider
        </Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
```

It should match what you use in the createMuiTheme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
           primary: green
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the Button's `color="secondary"`. While creating the palette, you are defining the color green for the primary attribute. I tried it in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-glitter-63559) to change the Button's color prop to `color="primary"` and it changes to green.